# How to get session and compare

Tags: php, session

This is session RememberMe

```
Array
(
    [formfields] => Array
        (
            [RememberMe] => 1
        )
)
```

The box should be checked

```
 <input <?php if(isset($_SESSION['RememberMe']) && $_SESSION['RememberMe'] ==1  ) { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?> type="checkbox" name="RememberMe" value="1" />
```

The checkbox was not checked. Why?

Comment: How about changing $_SESSION['RememberMe'] into $_SESSION['formfields']['RememberMe'] ?

Answer (score 0):

If the first array is your $_SESSION global you should be using `$_SESSION['formfields']['RememberMe']`